# Showing sets of markers on different layers of Google map

Tags: google-maps, layer, markers

I need to show a set of markers on a Google map.
I know markers can be added directly on a Google map but given that I have 3 sets of markers, one for shops, one for parks and another one for hotels, how can I show them on 3 different layers and so that later on using javascript, I be able to hide one set of markers by doing sort of:

```
myLayer2.setMap(null);
```

I have checked Panoramio layer but it needs the images first to be uploaded to [panoramio](http://panoramio.com), but in my case for some particular security reason I cannot upload them to panoramio. I will have images locally and set those at runtime based upon some criteria.

Is there some way to do layer based work without using panoramio approach?

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  What kind of [layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) are you asking about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Maps-API doesn't support this kind of custom layers(as you maybe know them from other map-API's like e.g. leaflet).

But it's not hard to achieve a similar feature.

You may use a `google.maps.MVCObject`. for every "layer" create a property for this MVCObject and set the value of this property to null or the google.maps.Map-instance(
depending on the desired initial state of the "layer")

```
var myLayers=new google.maps.MVCObject();
    myLayers.setValues({parks:null,shops:null,hotels:map});
    //hotels initially are visible
```

When you want to add a Overlay...e.g. a Marker, to a "layer", bind the map-property of that Overlay to the related property of the MVCObject:

```
   parkMarker=new google.maps.Marker({/*options*/});
   parkMarker.bindTo('map',myLayers,'parks');
```

To toggle the display of all features within that "layer" you only need to set the property of the MVCObject:

```
//show the parks
myLayers.set('parks',map);
//hide the hotels
myLayers.set('hotels',null);
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/UA85N/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/UA85N/)

Comment: Great answer Molle. I didn't know about MVCObject. Will dig deep into it now also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Molle, how can I completely remove either the layer itself from the map or a set of markers (e.g parks) from the layer?

Comment: It's not a real layer(it's not a container with child-elements where removing the parent would remove the childs too). To remove all parks-markers you must call `myLayers.set('parks',null);`

Comment: Actually I want to remove all old markers from map/layer, whenever a new query is sent to server. I was asking only because of this requirement.