# Custom Google Maps Layer for Markers and Polygons?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question about the googleMaps Javascript API. Is it possible to create a custom Layer that you can show/hide like the given layers such as traffic and bicycle layer?

I would like to have a own Layer for my Markers and another Layer for polygons.

thanks in advance

Comment: Will `KmlLayer` do what you want? Or `FusionTablesLayer`?

Comment: if i understood it correctly, then the informations for a these Layers are static values, but i need to add varying informations dynamically to such a layer

Comment: Not sure why you say that.  Perhaps you could be clearer on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I understood of your question that you would like to create a custom layer on your web site. You also need to change the layer informations at any time.

---

[Google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview) provides KML and GeoRSS data formats for "displaying geographic information".

We are going to introduce [KML](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) format.

---

You may create a KML file witch provides the informations for your layer. You can find an example of KML file [here](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml). Of course, you can edit this file any time on your server.

This is an example of editing a file on php:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/yourKLMFile.txt");
$file= str_replace("OldValue", "NewValue", $file);
echo ($file);
```

You also can provide personal data for your users or simply update your layer.

---

Next, JS.

Google maps api provides the `KmlLayer()` constructor witch creates your layers and display it on the map (since you have created it).

The constructor takes two important parameters:

- The URL of your KML file (probably on your server);
- The map in witch you want to display the layer.

This is a sample example:

```
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
    map: map
  });
```

---

This is a sample code spinnet wich resume all this:

```js
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
          map: map
        });
        }
```

```css
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

---

Remember that you can always update your data file in php.

You may consult the documentation about [KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview) layer and generally [google maps' layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) on google maps web site.

*Tell me a comment if you have some questions*

Comment: I'm not sure if a KML layer is what i need. I want to show devices on the map and i want to have a different layer for certain groups of devices. The Devices are Markers that have Labels and there shall be clusters as well. I have found a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/23033878/6433978 . but I think there is no way to get the clusters to work on that "layer"